# switch case (in C)

Tags: c, int, switch-statement, case, conditional-statements

we have 4 regions: `a` `b` `c` `d`

we want to put the numbers in these region.

how to do this using only switch statement:

```
 the number divisible by 10 and divisible by 7 ın region a
 the number divisible by 10 but not divisible by 7 ın region b
 the number not divisible by 10 but divisible by 7 ın region c
 the number not divisible by 10 and divisible by 7 ın region d
```

for example if:

```
input 770 out put is a

input 200 output b

input 154 output c
```

Comment: And please stop writing `1` instead of `i` and structure your questions better. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for help.

Comment: @chriz The OP is probably Turkish (as `ı` suggests, dotless i) and has issues typing `i`.

Comment: @chriz why did you edit the question and add 'php' in the title - this doesn't seem to be a php question.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this could work, not sure if this is what you're asking for, though:

```
switch ((number % 7 == 0) * 2 + (number % 10 == 0))
{
case 0:
  puts("d");
  break;
case 1:
  puts("b");
  break;
case 2:
  puts("c");
  break;
case 3:
  puts("a");
  break;
}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if this isn't what the OP asked for, though perhaps switch statements aren't the most appropriate way to go about it. I would use something like `printf("%c\n", "abcd"[(number % 10 > 0) * 2 + (number % 10 > 0)]);`, or regular old `if`-`else if`-`else` chains for this.

Comment: good answer(+1). I sugest to replace the multiplication by 2 to a shift with 1 (`<<1`)

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL Shifting won't do any difference. Any good contemporary compiler will figure out what's best anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
var1 = n % 7;
var2 = n % 10;

switch ( var1 ){
    case 0 :
       switch( var2 ){
                         case 0: printf("a");break;
                         default: printf("b");break;
                    }

    default :
       switch( var2 ){
                         case 0: printf("c");break;
                         default: printf("d");break;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One straight forward method is to use nested `switch` as an alternative to nested `if`s :):

```
char *foo(int i) {
    int imod10 = i%10;
    int imod7 = i%7;
    switch(imod10) {
        case 0:
            switch(imod7) {
                case 0:
                    return "A";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "B";
            }
            break;  
        default:
            switch(imod7) {
                case 0:
                    return "C";
                    break;
                default:
                    return "D";
            }
    }
}
```

See https://ideone.com/OacutE for an example on your test cases.